# Why can't you declare a static struct in C#, but they can have static methods?

Tags: c#

```
// OK
struct MyStruct
{
    static void Foo() { }
}

// Error
static struct MyStruct
{
}
```

Comment: Just the same for [delegates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6835766/why-can-a-net-delegate-not-be-declared-static) and [enums](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4567868/troubles-declaring-static-enum-c-sharp)

Comment: I answer this question in another question. I hope to help you.
[This is the link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59360219/6755993)

Answer (score 43):

Since you cannot create an instance of a static type, the behavior of `static struct` would be exactly the same as the behavior of `static class`. So, there is no reason for creating them. I think it would be theoretically possible to have a `static struct` but it would be confusing - how would you choose between `static class` and `static struct` if the behavior of the two was *exactly* the same?

Note that `static` methods inside a struct are quite useful as you can use them for operations related to the struct, for example `DateTime.TryParse` etc.

**Technically speaking** I don't think that the current C# compiler & runtime could produce something like a `static struct`, because internally (at the IL level) `static class` is a class that is marked as `abstract` and `sealed`. And I suppose that you cannot create a `struct` that would be `abstract` and `sealed` (in the IL).

Comment: fixed arrays can only be contained in structs, it would be nice to have a static one of these

Answer (score 15):

I think the key, really, is that a struct is a value type, not a reference type.  That would be like saying "There's only one instance of `int` for my entire program.  It can have different values, but only one at a time."  Further, whenever you pass a struct as an argument, it gets passed by value, that is, a copy of the struct is made and placed on the stack. This defeats the purpose of a static definition -- which should mean that there is only (ever) one instance of the thing being defined.  If what you are trying to create is really a Singleton, a class is a much better way to handle that given that it has much better creation semantics than a struct.

Answer (score 10):

The key point here is that the static modifier on a class enforces (among other things) that an instance of the class cannot be created. This is done by forcing a private constructor.

The CLR doesn't have any way to prevent an instance of a struct type from being created. Even if there is no public default constructor, simply declaring

```
struct S { }

S[] items = new S[]{1};
```

would create an instance of the struct with all of the associated memory set to zero bits.

Note that this is different from a reference type (class), where the same code would create a *reference* of the specified type (referencing no object aka null) but not an instance of the object itself.