# troubles declaring static enum, C#

Tags: c#, static, enums

Hi I'm trying to declar a static enum like so:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Lds.CM.MyApp.Controllers
{
    public class MenuBarsController : Controller
    {
        // Menu Bar enums
        public static enum ProfileMenuBarTab { MainProfile, Edit, photoGallery }

        public ActionResult cpTopMenuBar(string tabSelected)
        {
            ...
```

"
But I'm getting the following error:  "The modifier 'static' is not valid for this item."
I know it's something simple but I can't seem to see the problem.  Much thanks!

Comment: Just the same for [delegates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6835766/why-can-a-net-delegate-not-be-declared-static) and [structs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613376/why-cant-you-declare-a-static-struct-in-c-but-they-can-have-static-methods)

Answer (score 162, accepted):

Enums are types, not variables. Therefore they are 'static' per definition, you dont need the keyword.

```
public enum ProfileMenuBarTab { MainProfile, Edit, PhotoGallery }
```

Comment: enums are 'static' by definition but we can't use it inside static class why?

Comment: @user2323308 **10.1.1.3 Static classes**
A static class cannot be instantiated, cannot be used as a type and can contain only static members... 
A static class can only contain static members (**§10.3.7**). *Note that constants and nested types are classified as static members*. **10.3.7 Static and instance members**
Members of a class are either static members or instance members...
*...a constant or type declaration implicitly declares a static member.* ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification

Answer (score 17):

Take out `static`.
Enums are types, not members; there is no concept of a static or non-static enum.

You may be trying to make a static *field* of your type, but that has nothing to do with the type declaration.
(Although you probably shouldn't be making a static field)

Also, [you should not make `public` nested types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182162.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, it's been a long night.  I removed the "static" and all is well.  Also I was reading your link and it appears that a nested enum is an exception to your rule.  "Nested enumerators and protected types are exempt from this rule."

Comment: @SLaks, does this rule exception make sense to you?

Comment: @Ray: An enumerator (`IEnumerator<T>` implementation) has nothing to do with an enum.

Comment: "Nested enumerators and protected types are exempt from this rule."

Comment: @SLaks, He's got a public enum, you posted a link that says not to make public nested types, and I was just pointing out that according to the page you linked enums are exempt, so valid to make public.

Comment: @Aaron: An enumerator (`IEnumerator<T>` implementation) has nothing to do with an enum.

Comment: @SLaks, I guess it might be helpful if I read the comments before mine... Sorry for the repeat. But somethings still not clear; you keep saying that IEnumerator<T> has nothing to do with an enum, but why are you saying that? I don't see any relationship to his enum question and an interface for enumerating collections?

Comment: @Aaron: The MSDN guideline that you and Ray are quoting is talking about `IEnumerator<T>`.  (That what "Nested enumerators" means)

Comment: @SLaks, got it, I didn't recognize the distinction "enumeration" vs "enumerator" when reading it. That's a confusing rule exception, though makes sense after thinking about it for a while. Thanks.

Comment: @Aaron: It's used by all of the builtin generic collections (with structs, for some reason)

Comment: At some point in the intervening decade, the text in your original link must have been updated. It now reads "Nested _enumerations_ and protected types are exempt from this rule." (emphasis mine)

Answer (score 8):

You don't need to define it as static.When an enumerated type is compiled, the C# compiler turns each symbol into a constant field of the type . For example, the compiler treats the Color enumeration shown earlier
as if you had written code similar to the following:

```
internal struct Color : System.Enum {
            // Below are public constants defining Color's symbols and values
            public const Color White  = (Color) 0;
            public const Color Red    = (Color) 1;
            public const Color Green  = (Color) 2;
            public const Color Blue   = (Color) 3;
            public const Color Orange = (Color) 4;
            // Below is a public instance field containing a Color variable's value
            // You cannot write code that references this instance field directly
            public Int32 value__;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

An enum is a type, not a value. The modifier `static` doesn't make much sense there.

Comment: A class is a type too and can be static. and since you cannot access this enum with an instance of that class, it sure is static and therefore should use the static modifier, everything else is just inconsistent, but then again it's C#..

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to make an enum declartion static, ie a field of the type `ProfileMenuBarTab`. To declare a class (or whatever) in a class, leave the static out.

Answer (score 1):

Types in .Net can be either **value types** or **reference types**.

**Value types** -> `enums`, `structs` and `built-in values types`(bool, byte, short, int, long, sbyte, ushort, uint, ulong, char, double, decimal)

**Reference types** -> `classes`, `interfaces`, `delegates`, `dynamic` and `strings`

So, as you can see **enums are types**(like `classes` and `structs`, `etc`). more precisely **they are value types**. An important point about value types is that you should be able to create instances from them. For example, What is its benefit of `int` that is a struct (value type) if you can't create an instance of that for storing 2, 3 or any number in it?!

This is the general rule -> **you cannot create custom value types (`enums` and `structs`) with the `static` modifier.**

**Some points:**

- If you write your `enums` or `structs` directly in a `namespace` they can not be marked as `private` or `protected` just like other types. They can be just `public` or `internal` just like other types.
- If you write your `enums` or `structs` directly in a `class` you can mark them as `private` or `protected` too, as you can mark them as `internal` and `public`. `class` for inner types is like a `namespace` for types except you can mark inner types `private` or `public` too.