# C# Switch enum at runtime

Tags: c#, precompiled

I have two projects which reference the same precompiled (C#) dll.
This .dll contains a public enum in its namespace but:
Both projects have to use different values in this enum.

Is there a possibility to define something like that? (Pseudo Code)

```
namespace module
{

    #if ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["project"] == "Extern"

    public enum Roles
    {
        Admin = 0,
        User = 1,
        Vip = 2
    }

    #else /* "Intern" */

    public enum Roles
    {
        Admin = 0,
        Staff = 1,
        User = 2
    }

    #end
}
```

Important: This code has to be precompiled, so a preprocessor directive is not possible.

Comment: Just as a word of advice, all `enum`s are inherently static, so there is no need to "redeclare" them as such. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4567868/troubles-declaring-static-enum-c-sharp

Comment: Seems really misleading and I am not sure even if I would want to know if it is possible..

Comment: I don't think the `static` in `public static enum` is doing anything for you or is not going to work - [troubles declaring static enum, C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4567868/troubles-declaring-static-enum-c-sharp)

Comment: Yeah they don't need to be static :) (Edited Question)

Comment: Why you cannot have two separate enums? What's the problem you're trying to solve? Maybe there are others solutions, than have two enums (and as @KonradKokosa points out, it's really misleading).

Comment: The .dll is precompiled and does not know in which of the two projects it is running.

Comment: You can't have a single enum that's different depending on what (or who) is using it.  That doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Kyle I tought so, but a little spark in me wanted to ask here if there is not "trick" to do such a thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be likely to confuse people but if you really want something in that direction, with a light modification, what about:

```
    public enum Roles
    {
        Admin = 0,
        Staff = 1,
        User = 1,
        Vip = 2,
        UserInternal = 2,
    }
```

Note I had to rename one of your names.

You can compare the integer value and even with the names with will be true (`Roles.Staff == Roles.User` is `true`.

But like in the comments I would not highly recommend it.

Answer (score 1):

You can have that, but they both can't be in the same namespace. You could have one be `module.Extern.Roles`, and the other be `module.Intern.Roles`, but if you want them in the same namespace, you'd have to combine the values into a single enum or change the name of one of them.