# Why does the C# compiler not complain when we use struct function inside the static methods without defining them static?

Tags: c#, struct, static

Why does the compiler not complain when we use struct function inside the static methods without defining them static?

Example:

```
    struct CustomerName{
    Public String firstname, lastname;
    Public String Name() => firstname + " " +lastname;
}
Public static void main(){
    CustomerName MyName ;
    MyName.firstname = "Kidus";
    MyName.lastname = "Tekeste";
    Console.WriteLine(MyName.Name());
}
```

This works fine in visual studio but I wonder why it worked with out it being made static. like this:

```
 static struct CustomerName{
    Public String firstname, lastname;
    Public String Name() => firstname + " " +lastname;
}
```

Comment: First structs cannot be static.  Second if it were a class it would still work because you would have to create an instance (maybe your confusion is because there isn't a `new CustomerName()` call).  Static means you would only access members via the class name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it would have been a class, would it be clearer? Same behaviour.

Firstly, struct cant be *static* [Simple explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613376/why-cant-you-declare-a-static-struct-in-c-but-they-can-have-static-methods)

You declare and define a struct somewhere. By not defining it as *static* You essentially say it can be instantiated to an object of type `CustomerName`.
In your `Main()` you instantiate an object of this type and call it `MyName` and assign values to its fields. Works just as intended, don't you agree?

Comment: The _Simple explanation_ was really helpful. Thanks!